# MySQL Insert on duplicate key causes DEADLOCK

Tags: mysql, debugging, deadlock

I am using MySQL in my program and going to use `insert on duplicate key update` statement. Many information shows that this statement may cause a deadlock.

There's the bug report about MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98324.

And there's one of the articles about deadlock for a specific version: https://medium.com/@mingwho/mysql-deadlock-caused-by-insert-on-duplicate-key-update-893ef30993a8

In order to avoid deadlock I want to repeat this bug. `5.7.26`, `5.7.29`, `8.0.20` didn't repeat this bug even if I follow the operation in the article I post above.

1. Run a docker image `docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7.26`
2. Create a table like this:

```
create table uod
(
    id  int auto_increment
        primary key,
    uk  int           not null,
    seq int default 0 null,
    constraint uod_pk2
        unique (uk)
);
```

3. Insert initial data

```
INSERT INTO uod (id, uk, seq) VALUES (1, 10, 0);
INSERT INTO uod (id, uk, seq) VALUES (2, 20, 0);
INSERT INTO uod (id, uk, seq) VALUES (3, 30, 0);
```

4. Try repeat the bug (Execute SQL with manual TX)

```
-- TX1:
insert into uod(uk) value (11) on duplicate key update seq=seq+1

-- TX2:
insert into uod(uk) value (12) on duplicate key update seq=seq+1

-- TX3:
insert into uod(uk) value (13) on duplicate key update seq=seq+1
```

Nothing happen!! No bugs occur!! It's great but I feel worried.

Any way to repeat this bug about deadlock.